# In a Neural Network if the input is > 1 or < -1 then should an activation function be applied before propagation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am creating my first ANN and am using the 'stock standard' Iris flower data sheet. Some of the input are as follows: 1.3, 4.0, 2.8, etc.

Should these values be placed through an activation function so they are <1 and will propagating without this cause any problems?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normalization removes geometrical biases towards some of the dimensions of the data vectors. In this way every bit of data gets treated in a "fair" manner. Another way of posing this is to realize that all learning algorithms depend on numerical properties so one should try to avoid small numbers, large numbers, and large differences.

If you do not normalize your inputs between (0,1) or (-1,1) you could not equally distribute importance of each input,  thus naturally  large values become dominant according to less values during ANN training.

The important thing is comparability  of inputs.  For example there are two inputs to your ann, x1 and x2. x1 varies from to 0 to 0.5 and x2 varies from 0 to 1000. A change of x1 of 0.5  is 100 percent change where as a change of x2 by 0.5 is only a change of 0.05%. Hence normalization helps.